# DOM element properties undefined - jquery / ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running into a problem with a Rails app I'm working on.  Objects are successfully saving to the database but when they are rendered in the DOM, their properties are initially showing up as undefined.  When I refresh the browser everything is fine.

I'm not sure where this problem needs to be addressed.

Document.ready:

```
$(function() {
    fetchClientsAndJobs();
});
```

The functions in question:

```
function fetchClientsAndJobs() {
    $.get('/clients').done(function(clientData) {
        clientData.forEach(renderClient);
        $.get('/jobs').done(function(jobData) {
            jobData.forEach(renderJob)
        });
    });
}
```

and:

```
function addClient() {    
    var clientNameInput = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var clientRateInput = $('input[name="rate"]').val();
    var clientEmailAddress = $('input[name="email-address"]').val();
    var newClient = {
        client: {
            name: clientNameInput,
            rate: clientRateInput,
            email_address: clientEmailAddress
        }
    };
    $.post('/clients', newClient).done(function(clientData) {
        renderClient(clientData)
        });
    $('input[name="name"]').val('');
    $('input[name="rate"]').val('');
    $('input[name="email-address"]').val('');
}
```

Controller action:

```
def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
    @client.user_id = session[:current_user]
    if @client.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        redirect_to new_client_path
    end     
end
```

Any input would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? Usually the phrase "When I refresh the browser everything is fine" points to a misunderstanding of how to write javascript with turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

Your client side code seems to be expecting the post to the create action to return data about the newly created client (since you are calling `renderClient` in your `done`.

However your create action redirects to the root of your app - I don't know what that renders but almost certainly not the data you expect.

Typically you'd have something along the lines of

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @client } #or whatever you are using to serialize your models to json
  format.html { redirect_to root_path }
end
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks, I appreciate it.  Happy New Year!